# Correct way to add a sound to UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

What is the most correct way to add a sound to a UIAlertView?

Should I subclass it and then play a system sound when the view appears?

Or would it be more correct, not to subclass but instead call a separate method to play a sound when it appears?

Can anyone recommend a control that plays sound and looks prettier than UIAlertView?

Comment: Local Notifications don't fire when the application is active or rather they do, but you have to catch the notification in a delegate method and use your own method of alert anyway, which brings me back to uialertview with sound.

Comment: if you want to put player on noti.alertBody then is may be not possible to customize alertBody of notification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can achieve this by using `AVAudioPlayer` bellow code:-

Set dalagete of `UIAlertView` in .h file like:-

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

**in .m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/foo.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 1;
    [audioPlayer play];
    [alert show]; 
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex==0) {
        [audioPlayer stop];

    }

}
```

**EDIT**

*NOTE:-* Do not forget to Add `AVAudio framework` And if you wish to sound playing till not press Button of `UIAlertView` then set `audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;`

Comment: Thank you for the answer above, would it be more elegant to subclass UIAlertView itself? to encapsulate the sound playing within it's class?

Comment: may be you can with subclass i haven't trying like this way

Comment: AVFoundation is all that shows up in Xcode present dat but I imagine most developers will figure that out!