# IOS alert message with sound

Tags: ios, xcode

Does anyone know how to implement an alert message with sound? I essentially want it to use a default iOS alert noise repeatedly while the message is up and off when dismissed.

Right now I have the message implemented as such:

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Alert Message" 
                                                message:@"Noise should be playing until you push 'OK'!" 
                                               delegate:nil 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct way to add a sound to UIAlertView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160277/correct-way-to-add-a-sound-to-uialertview)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/foo.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 1;
    [audioPlayer play];
    [alert show]; 
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex==0) {
        [audioPlayer stop];

    }
}
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18160299/3202193