# Sound with UIAlert / UIAlertController

Tags: swift, xcode, audio, uialertcontroller

Hi I am wondering if it's possible to play a sound with UIAlert? It seems to be possible according to the following post but I am struggling to translate Obj-C to Swift. Any help is appreciated!

[IOS alert message with sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309680/ios-alert-message-with-sound)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way you can achieve it in swift.

First of all you need to performa that action in `viewWillAppear` if you are following the post you have included in your question.

Then create the `audioPlayer` which will play your sound as shown below:

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
```

then assign `URL` from `Bundle`

```
let resourcePath = Bundle.main.resourcePath
let stringURL = resourcePath! + "foo.mp3"
let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: stringURL)
```

Then play it before your alert will appear like:

```
audioPlayer?.play()
```

Now create your alert like:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in
    self.audioPlayer?.stop()
 }))

 audioPlayer?.play()
 self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And your complete code will be:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let resourcePath = Bundle.main.resourcePath
        let stringURL = resourcePath! + "foo.mp3" //change foo to your file name you have added in project
        let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: stringURL)

        audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: url)
        audioPlayer?.numberOfLoops = 1

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in
            self.audioPlayer?.stop()
        }))

        audioPlayer?.play()
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't quite work so I changed the code to 

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "disconnect", withExtension: "wav")
                self.audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: url!, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.wav.rawValue)
                self.audioPlayer?.numberOfLoops = 1

Now it's working great. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You didn't gave that much info too. Happy to help you.. :)

Comment: Apology didn't make it clear. for some reason, your method of get the URL to the sound file didn't work but didn't crash the app either... strange..